# What is the meaning of “heavier than heavenly”

Tags: meaning

**What is the meaning of “heavier than heavenly”?**

I googled that but I didn't find the meaning. Google said it's as same as “heavier than heaven” and it's the name of a 2001 biography of musician Kurt Cobain, the frontman of the grunge band Nirvana. So what's the meaning?

I also found [this link](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080621182227AAhtItd). According to that, it means **Not suitable for heaven (too good for heaven)**. Is this correct?

### Update

By the way, I found this phrase in song called *On Our Way* by *Lana Del Rey*. [Here.](http://www.metrolyrics.com/on-our-way-lyrics-lana-del-rey.html)

Comment: Please provide the context where you encountered this phrase.

Comment: I think it's probably pointless looking for some obscure-yet-precise *meaning*. Most likely all such variants are just (lame) "puns" based on the superficially similar form of two unrelated words.

Comment: But there is [this from 1986](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22sin+is+huge+it+is+heavier%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) *Then the Buddha said to that Brahmin "Men's sin is huge; it is **heavier than heaven**, and thicker than the earth, higher than the square marking stone every side one elbow length."* Should we conclude from that that *thicker than the earth* means *more evil than you can possibly imagine?*

Comment: I read it as meaning "Too weighted down by earthly concerns to be ethereal [or light of spirit]." But there is also a residual sense of _heavy_ in its 1960s sense of "deep and difficult and meaningful," with the implicit contrasting characterization of _heavenly_ as meaning "idealized or trouble-free."

Comment: @Sven: To find that 1986 reference I had to restrict my search to C20, because current references are swamped by the Kurt Cobain book. I repeat my assertion that the semantic content is at or near zero, but it's worth noting that Nirvana (Cobain's band) did a UK tour in 1989 called "Heavier Than Heaven". At that time [*the lead singer, Tad Doyle, was very obese; the name which was thought up by the tour promoters, was meant in part to poke fun at the inaccurate idea that Tad alone weighed more than all of the members of Nirvana put together.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavier_Than_Heaven)

Comment: ...plus of course one could describe much of Cobain's/Nirvana's music as "heavy" in several different ways (musically dirge-like, shades of heavy metal, deep/heavy lyrics, etc.). Basically, it's all "pun fodder".

Answer (score 1):

This phrase is not idiomatic and, as such, its meaning is going to be open to quite a bit of interpretation. As your question (and the comments) note, there are two distinct phrases here:

> 1. heavier than heaven
> 2. heavier than heavenly

The first is primarily used by the Kurt Cobain biography and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavier_Than_Heaven) explains the title:

> Cross [the author] took the name "Heavier Than Heaven" from a tour Nirvana did with the band Tad in the UK. The lead singer, Tad Doyle, was very obese; the name which was thought up by the tour promoters, was meant in part to poke fun at the inaccurate idea that Tad alone weighed more than all of the members of Nirvana put together.

Tour promoters don't need a specific, coherent meaning for phrases. They just need something that sounds cool. Since the phrase never entered a wide usage, there is no specific meaning outside of a particular context.

---

The second usage is just a song lyric which can mean virtually anything. Lyrics and poems are often created with multiple or ambiguous meanings in mind. The specific context of "heavier than heavenly" does not help much:

> you don't know what you've done to me
>
> you're heavier than heavenly
>
> life on the run has set me free, me free now

This site is not the appropriate place to creatively interpret song lyrics. The only person who can authoritatively explain the intended meaning is Lana Del Rey.

---

Therefore, neither usage has a dedicated, unambiguous meaning.

Answer (score -1):

In the context of the lyric, it seems like she is saying that he is making her life heavier and darker instead of blissful and light as a lover should. After tossing him, she's on the run and she's free and lighter.